# JQuery, load, parse, sum and display from external page

Tags: jquery, math, html-table, load, external

I'm trying to load an external page which contains a table like this:

```
<table id="uniquedatatable">
 <tr class="row"> 
  <td class="num col"><a> 1 </a></td>
  <td class="str col"><a>Text</a></td>
  <td class="num col"><a>  7</a></td>
  <td class="str col"><a>Text</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

*Notice the whitespace's in the class names of the td's and around the numbers (1,7).

I need to find all cell's (td's) with class "num col", get the numeric value between the a tag'a and sum all the values. Last I need to display this value on my own page.

So the result I would get from the above table should be: 1 + 7 = 8.

I've gotten this far:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <p id="result"></p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   var url = "http://someurl";
   var sum = 0;

   $('#result').load('url #uniquedatatable tr td.num col a', function() {
     sum += Number($(this).text());
   });

   _gel('result').innerHTML = sum;
 </script>
```

Realizing something is wrong (close to being correct I hope :)), I need help connecting the "dots" here so that I can:

1. Calculate the sum (this is the "big" problem :S)
2. Write the result back.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the selector for the load call, you can probably leave out the "col" since the real determining factor appears to be ".num". Also, the syntax is off there, it should be "td.num.col" if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        var url = "<LOCAL_URL>";    
        var sum = 0;     
        $('#result').load(url, function() { 
            $("#uniquedatatable tr td.num.col a", "#result" ).each(function(){
                sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
            });
                     _gel('result').innerHTML = sum;  

        });     
        </script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks :). I keep getting 0. Is there a way to check that the load() is successfull and maybe print the entire page just to make sure?

Comment: Ahh no sry, missed that one. Will give it a try :)

Comment: Is there any way to do it with a remote url? Like using something like <script type="text/javascript" src="http:\\someurl">?

Comment: Not in a direct way because of the cross domain issues. You can still use a URL local to your server which returns your the HTML returned by the remote url using server side processing (curl for PHP etc)

Answer (score 1):

for calc you can use `sum += parseInt($(this).text());`